# React-Hooks-Forms: Why when copy-paste correct digits number lenght that triggers the min/max lenght validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

In my React app, I'm using the `react-hook-form` inside a Material UI v5 `TextField` input. This input is used to validate a 6 digits number code length.

When I copy-paste the numbers the validation is triggered and the error come ups as per the screenshot and I have no idea how to fix it

the error occurs when I copy a number as `123 456` which is formatted by the below script `handleFormatCode` to `123456` on the `onChange` trigger.

I'm without ideas on what causing this issue and how to solve it.

[image: Error]

The code involved in this input as

```
<TextField
            id="token"
            name="token"
            autoComplete="off"
            autoFocus
            label={
              <FormattedMessage defaultMessage="Please enter your 2FA token" />
            }
            placeholder="### ###"
            inputRef={register({
              maxLength: {
                value: 6,
                message: '2FA token must be 6 characters long',
              },
              minLength: {
                value: 6,
                message: '2FA token must be 6 characters long',
              },
              setValueAs: value => formatCode(value),
            })}
            onChange={handleFormatCode} //111 111
            fullWidth
            error={Boolean(errors?.token)}
            helperText={get(
              errors,
              'token.message',
              <FormattedMessage
                defaultMessage="Please enter the code from your {channel}"
                values={{ channel: get2FADevice(type2fa) }}
              />,
            )}
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <VpnKey color="primary" />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
          />
```

Inside the text field are used the following scripts to format the input

```
const handleFormatCode = event => {
    console.log('HERE');
    event.target.value = formatPastedCode(event.target.value);
  };

export const formatCode = (value = '', oldValue = '') => {
  const digits = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').substring(0, 6);
  const len = digits.length;
  return (value.length > oldValue.length && len >= 3) ||
    (value.length < oldValue.length && len > 3)
    ? `${digits.substr(0, 3)} ${digits.substr(3)}`
    : digits;
};

export const formatPastedCode = (value) => {
  const digits = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').substring(0, 6);
  const normalizeDigits = trimWhitespace(digits);
  return normalizeDigits; // 111 222
}
```

The above scripts serve to format the code to the right format

Comment: It seems to work fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xfk1vs?file=src%2FApp.js, if you can't reproduce the issue it's hard to help.

Comment: @CesarePolonara In your case is not showing the error message when I try to write less or more than 6 numbers.
I should not avoid seeing the error message if the numbers are more or less than 6.
However, I tried to replicate the issue but I'm unable to do it cannot get same issue with same code on editors online :(

Comment: I logged the errors and as you can see the errors object is empty even if you paste a bad formatted string + spaces + mnumbers, since it gets formatted and trimmed before being validated. If you can't reproduce it it's something related to the environment, try upgrading react-hook-form to the last version, it has some breaking changes.

Comment: Ok will check the new version then as I don't have more clues why that happening actually

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after many hours of tries.
I had to add a custom validation and
I added a method using the `setValue` of `useForm`

The code of the method added on the `onChange`

```
const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, setError, errors } = useForm();

const handleFormatCode = event => {
            setValue('token', formatCode(event.target.value), { shouldValidate: true });
      };
```